# How to change locate service (sym_%) tables to another database

Tags: symmetricds

I have several database: syncdb (for replication) and servicedb (for SymmetricDS tables)

Is it possible to store sym_% tables in another database?

Connection string:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/servicedb
```

Trigger row:

```sql
INSERT INTO servicedb.sym_trigger (trigger_id,source_catalog_name,source_table_name,channel_id,create_time,last_update_time)
VALUES ('trigger_sync_table','syncdb','sync_table','channel_dbc',NOW(),NOW());
```

When I run bin/sym I get an error:

> TriggerRouterService - Could not find any database tables matching
> 'syncdb.sync_table' in the datasource that is configured

Comment: I have managed to store it in another schema. Not sure if possible in another DB as there’s only one DB connection per engine to be configured and most probably that would be hurting your system performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to put Symmetric's tables in a separate database to your application tables. You specified the `source_catalog_name`, so your `sym_trigger` entry is correct.

You need to grant the following permissions to your `db.user` to allow access to the tables in the `syncdb` database. Replace "symmetric" with the value of your `db.user` property.

```
grant trigger on *.* to symmetric;
grant create routine on *.* to symmetric;
grant alter routine on *.* to symmetric;
grant process on *.* to symmetric;
```